# Key "1" for array with keys "0, +, -" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I have swapped an array around in order to fix this deprecation;

> The value "false" for the "choices_as_values" option of the "choice"
>   form type (Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType) is
>   deprecated since version 2.8 and will not be supported anymore in 3.0.
>   Set this option to "true" and flip the contents of the "choices"
>   option instead.

But now I am getting the following error;

> Key "1" for array with keys "0, +, -" does not exist in
>   src/MyBundle/Resources/views/Consult/show.html.twig at line 467

This is my function/array after swapping the key and value around;

```
public static function enumZeroPlusMinus()
{
    return array(
        '0' => '0',
        '+' => '1',
        '-' => '2',
    );
}
```

and this is my the line the new error complains about;

```
<td>{{ entity.enumZeroPlusMinus[entity.foreFootSupportLeft] }}</td>
```

I don't understand the error. Can somebody perhaps explain and help me with this one? It is probably something small. Or could it be that Doctrine has an issue? Because the '0', '1', and '2' is the values stored in the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your array doesnt have a key `1`, it has `'0', '+', '-'`.

Unless Ive misunderstaood, you need to do something like this:

```
$array = enumZeroPlusMinus();
echo $array[ array_search('1', $array) ];
```

also, just throw your original array through [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) when trying to deal with the deprecation warning.